# TinyMCE - stripping tags and then adding tags - weird behavior

Tags: php, html, css, tinymce, styling

I have a tinyMCE textarea on my page.  I'm trying to create a "quote and reply" function for a forum program and this portion looks like this:

```
if ($special == 'quote') {
        $dataContent['message'] = strip_tags($dataContent['message'], '<p>');
        echo '<em>'.$post->authorName.'&nbsp;said:<br />'.$dataContent['message'].'</em><br /><br /><br />';
        }
    echo '</textarea>';
```

Alright, simple.  So, it should strip all tags except the line formatting (`<p>` tags) and then add an `<em>` tag to the entire thing to italicize it, I have `em` set up in the styling to always be `font-style: italic`.

Okay, so here's what's happening - the `$post->authorName` said: portion is displaying in italics but the `$dataContent['message']` part is not.  Both are enclosed in the `<em>` tag.  Now, if I take the allowing of `<p>` tags away from the strip tags call, it all italicizes.  I'm stumped - what would cause this to happen?  I just want to keep the basic formatting of line breaks and still italicize the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked that `<p>` inside `<em>` is not 'italicized' :) but inside `<i>` does. Try it.

Comment: <i> is a deprecated tag, correct?  I'd rather not use it, there should be a way to accomplish this without using deprecated tags you would think, no?  I tried adding p em and em p font-style: italic; to my stylesheet and that didn't cut it either.  Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: I can't find <i> is deprecated, but anyway I agree is a much better idea to enclose those <p> in a container and assign the style using css.